# Can't display other data from the database on to webpage

Tags: php

I am building a login system and I have got it to display the username and password printed on another page. However, for some reason I can't display the user's email on the page. All I want is the user logs in and in the other page it displays their username and email address from the database.

Here's my code: usersignin.php

```
 <?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="membersTI"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    session_start();

    // username and password sent from form 
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 


    if($_POST['myusername'] == "" or $_POST['mypassword'] == ""){
        echo "Empty Field";
    }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1){
    $_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
    $_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;
    $_SESSION['myemail']=$myemail;

    header("location:login_success.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }

    ?>
```

login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION["myusername"]){
    header("location:login.php");
} else
    $user = $_SESSION['myusername'];
    $pass = $_SESSION['mypassword'];
    $email = $_SESSION['myemail'];
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<title>Member's club</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login_success.css" />
<body>


<div class="table" id = "main">
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="cell header" id="mainstory">
            HEY! <?php echo $user;?><?php echo $email?>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>


</html>
</body>
```

Any suggestions? It's been a year since I touched php and a lot has changed and some of them have been deprecated.

Comment: You're never setting a value to `$myemail` before you save it to `$_SESSION['myemail']` so what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, *something something* MySQL extension deprecated, *something something* Mysqli / PDO

Comment: wait MYSQL is depricated?

Comment: The PHP extension is. See http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: Oh okay. I can't believe so much has changed over a year :o

Comment: Why do some PHP code get depricated? I don't see Java code get depricated yearly.

Comment: Pfft, a year! There's been a warning on all the *mysql* pages recommending you use something else for many, many years

Comment: No deprecations in Java, are you serious? They don't have the [@Deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotation for nothing

Comment: On the common features of java. Anyway, off to reading php again!

Comment: Plenty of common features ~ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/deprecated-list.html

Comment: Okay. To be honest, I haven't encountered many depricated features using Java. I built a login system using php last year and it seems useless now. Looks like I have to start over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because $myemail is not set. So giving $_SESSION['myemail'] the value will not work.
You will have to fetch the email from database first.

```
if($count==1){
    while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $_SESSION['myusername']=$user['username']; // 'username' = the name you use on database
        $_SESSION['mypassword']=$user['password']; // 'password' = the name you use on database
        $_SESSION['myemail']=$user['email']; // Same as 'username' and 'password'

       header("location:login_success.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `while` loop seems redundant, especially considering you've already asserted there's only one row

Comment: Looks like I will have to change some php code for the database part

Answer (score 0):

Your $myemail isn't set. Just pull it from the SQL statement, since you're checking for the username and password match.

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="membersTI"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name ) or die("cannot connect"); 

session_start();

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

if($_POST['myusername'] == "" or $_POST['mypassword'] == ""){
  echo "Empty Field";
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( mysqli_query($con,$sql) );

//Just check for a result, as it will return blank if failed.
if( $result ) {
  $_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
  $_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;
  $_SESSION['myemail']=$result['user_email'];
  header("location:login_success.php");
} else {
  echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

You also need to add a `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or another method of escaping your SQL statement. Otherwise you are open to SQL injection.

If somebody sets your $_POST['username'] field to be `"); DROP TABLE; "` your table will be dropped.